# Problem with matrix shapes while using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, array-broadcasting

Here's my code for a machine learning problem I'm attempting. Note that the .txt file being read has three columns. Mostly I'm trying to keep the array shapes in the form of (m,n) rather than (m,), whether it's a square matrix or a vector. As for vectors, I'm keeping their shapes as (m,1) (column vector) rather than (1,m) (row vector).

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

X = np.loadtxt('ex2data1.txt', delimiter=',')[:,:-1]
y = np.loadtxt('ex2data1.txt', delimiter=',')[:,[-1]]
# Add the bias column to X
X = np.hstack(( np.ones((len(X),1)) , X ))

# Model parameter initialization
theta = np.zeros(( len(X[0,:]), 1 ))

def cost(X, y, theta):
    h = 1/(1+np.exp(-X@theta))
    return (-1/len(X))*( (y.T @ np.log(h)) + ((1-y).T @ np.log(1-h)) )

def gradient(X, y, theta):
    h = 1/(1+np.exp(-X@theta))
    return (1/len(X))*(X.T@(h-y))

J, grad = cost(X, y, theta), gradient(X, y, theta)

print('Cost at initial theta (zeros):\n', J)
print('Expected cost (approx): 0.693\n')
print('Gradient at initial theta (zeros): \n', grad)
print('Expected gradient (approx):\n -0.1000\n -12.0092\n -11.2628\n')
-------------------------------------
Cost at initial theta (zeros):      |
 [[0.69314718]]                     |
Expected cost (approx): 0.693       |
                                    |
Gradient at initial theta (zeros):  |
 [[ -0.1       ]                    |
 [-12.00921659]                     |
 [-11.26284221]]                    |
Expected gradient (approx):         |
 -0.1000                            |
 -12.0092                           |
 -11.2628                           |
-------------------------------------
X.shape, y.shape, theta.shape, grad.shape, J.shape
----------------------------------------------|
((100, 3), (100, 1), (3, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1))  |
----------------------------------------------|
theta, cost = opt.fmin_ncg(f=cost, x0=theta, fprime=gradient, args=(X,y))
print(cost)
print(theta)
```

I've enclosed the intermediate output in boxes. Calling the fmin_ncg function gives me the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-86d5d7f476c2> in <module>
----> 1 theta, cost = opt.fmin_ncg(f=cost, x0=theta, fprime=gradient, args=(X,y))
      2 print(cost)
      3 print(theta)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in fmin_ncg(f, x0, fprime, fhess_p, fhess, args, avextol, epsilon, maxiter, full_output, disp, retall, callback)
   1454 
   1455     res = _minimize_newtoncg(f, x0, args, fprime, fhess, fhess_p,
-> 1456                              callback=callback, **opts)
   1457 
   1458     if full_output:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback, xtol, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, **unknown_options)
   1535     k = 0
   1536     gfk = None
-> 1537     old_fval = f(x0)
   1538     old_old_fval = None
   1539     float64eps = numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).eps

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    291     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    292         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 293         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    294 
    295     return ncalls, function_wrapper

<ipython-input-129-7fd4b6f3144e> in cost(X, y, theta)
      1 def cost(X, y, theta):
----> 2     h = 1/(1+np.exp(-X@theta))
      3     return (-1/len(X))*( (y.T @ np.log(h)) + ((1-y).T @ np.log(1-h)) )
      4 
      5 def gradient(X, y, theta):

ValueError: shapes (3,) and (100,1) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 100 (dim 0)
```

I don't have the first clue on why this is happening. I took care in defining all matrices to have the correct dimensions, and I'm pretty sure I didn't define any of the matrices as having shape (3,).

Would be really glad for any help or guidance with this.

Comment: `opt.fmin_ncg` flattens `x0`.  Its docs aren't real clear about this, but it is common behavior in the `scipy.opitimize` functions.  I verified it by looking at the code (a couple of function calls down).

Comment: @hpaulj: So basically `theta` gets flattened from (3,1) to (3,). Any way to rectify this mess?

Comment: Does a `theta` of shape (3,1) contain any vital information that (3,) does not?  Can't you just reshape `X` at the start of `cost` and `gradient`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question in case anybody else runs into the same problem. Both the cost (function to be minimized) and the gradient functions need to have x0 (theta in this case) as their first parameter. In addition, the gradient function has to return an array of shape (n, ) rather than (n, 1). The parameter vector x0 also needs to have the shape (n, ) instead of (n, 1).